# How to Terminate the In Progress workflow in SharePoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow

How to Terminate the `In Progress` workflow in SharePoint Designer.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What version of SharePoint are we talking about here?

Answer (score 4):

There is a `Stop workflow` action that is only available in SharePoint Workflow 2010.

[image]

In SharePoint 2013, the `Stop workflow` action is deprectaed, in this case,

- you have to create a SharePoint Workflow 2010 with `Stop workflow` action, then start it from your SharePoint 2013 workflow using `Start a List workflow` action

[image]

- Otherwise, you only have `End workflow` in the Transition section in SharePoint workflow 2013

[image]

---

**To cancel a workflow from UI**

**First,** You must have the `Manage Lists` permission to cancel a workflow.

**Steps**

- Open your list > click on `...` for a specific item that you need to cancel its workflow > click Workflows.
- Under Running Workflows, click the name of the workflow that you want to cancel.
- On the Workflow Status page, under Workflow Information, click **Terminate this workflow now**.

> **Note:**  If the Terminate this workflow now link does not appear, you do
>   not have the correct permission to perform this task. You must have the `Manage Lists` permission to cancel a workflow.

**Ref:** [Cancel a workflow in progress](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Cancel-a-workflow-in-progress-539cff97-34f0-427d-8429-f8058016810d)

---

**To cancel all workflow using PowerShell**

If you are using SharePoint On-Prem and you need to cancel all SharePoint Workflows in Progress for a specific list, you should use the below Powershell script

```
#Your Shaeproint Site URL
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://yoursharepointserver.com/yoursubsite";
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true;    

#Your List Name
$list = $web.Lists["YourListName"];
$count = 0

#Loop through all Items in List then loop through all Workflows on each List Items.         
foreach ($listItem in $list.Items) 
{
    foreach ($workflow in $listItem.Workflows) 
    {
        #Disregard Completed Workflows 
        if(($listItem.Workflows | where {$_.InternalState -ne "Completed"}) -ne $null)
        {
            #Cancel Workflows        
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager]::CancelWorkflow($workflow);      
            write-output "Workflow cancelled for : " $listItem.Title;  
        }
    }
}
$web.Dispose();
```

**Credit to:**  [Easiest way of cancelling all SharePoint Workflows in Progress](http://www.macaalay.com/2013/11/07/easiest-way-of-cancelling-all-sharepoint-workflows-in-progress/)

---

Comment: Hi, Actually my issue is we would like to terminate or cancel the workflow automatically. EX: once item will create based on drop down value one approval workflow is running and before approved user will edit the item and change the drop down value and submit. in this case we need to stop the running workflow and need to start second work flow.

Comment: Check the updated answer!