# How to clear orphaned workflows

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, workflow2013

How can I clear/reset the workflow count for a list. This list items have already been deleted, but the "Workflows in progress" numbers are still the same. I would like to reset these numbers to zero. Plus I'm worried that these are in fact still pending and using up server resources.

[image]

What confused me is that the "Workflow Health" status seems to be correct.
[image]

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it with some help from the post below.
https://www.sharepointeurope.com/wfinstancemanagementdb-in-workflow-manager/

The **dbo.Instances** table within the **WFInstanceManagementDB** database is key here.

[image]

After deleting all orphaned/suspended workflows here, the progress list was cleared.

[image]

*Finally piece of mind!*

Although this mind not be the best recommended way, it definitely worked for me. So just in case some one has the same issue, make sure you use with causion!

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel the in progress workflow by PowerShell. Please refer to [old discussion here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232848/how-to-terminate-the-in-progress-workflow-in-sharepoint-designer) for sample code and reference.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but that's not what i was looking for. This works only for list items that are still in the list. My list is basically empty. All items have been deleted and the recycle bin (both stages) has been emptied out.

Comment: i need to be able to delete/clear orphaned workflow references for list items that have been deleted. running the cleanup job didn't work either.

Comment: Are the deleted items still in recycle bin?

Comment: No, all items had already been purged.