# How to bulk cancel [Errored] workflow instances that either run via a Site Workflow or a List Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sharepoint-on-prem

What would the PowerShell command be to cancel all the `Errored` workflow instances that occured within a `Site Workflow` or a List Workflow` by ignoring any already [Cancelled] workflow instances.

As well as to ensure the cancelation of workflow instances where the `Item` and/or the Author does not exist.
I tried to use this solution: [How to Terminate the In Progress workflow in SharePoint Designer?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232848/how-to-terminate-the-in-progress-workflow-in-sharepoint-designer) but it does not cancel any errored instances at all.

As a bonus maybe at the end to say:
*" xx workflow instances cancelled from XYZ list or site workflow"*

Answer (score 0):

Please run below PowerShell as administrator.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "site collection URL"

$list = $web.Lists["list name"]
    
foreach ($item in $list.Items)
 {
   foreach ($wf in $item.Workflows)
     {
     #Check for the particular workflow
        if($wf.InternalState -match 'Error')
        {  
            #Cancel Workflow
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager]::CancelWorkflow($wf)                 
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I have used this code before and it does not cancel them. By the way, the `Workflow State` is [Errored] which I also have tried but no luck.  By the way, there are items within the list which do not exist anymore ...

Comment: Workflow 2010 or workflow 2013?

Comment: We are using SharePoint 2016 on-prem.

Comment: Ok, I know the environment. Whether you want to bulk cancel errored 2010 workflow instances or 2013 workflow instances? This will make a difference in PowerShell.

Comment: I would like to have a PowerShell which goes through a SubSite and stops any workflow intances which are [Errored] but ignores any Completed or Cancelled instances. At same time, it should also look for List Workflows and Site Workflows. Note: some items may have been deleted and the workflow instance may not find its inital item.